# How to get multiple content areas in hapi.js ejs layouts?

Tags: node.js, ejs, hapi.js, hapijs-vision

I would like to define information in a template that is rendered in the containing layout using [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs) in hapi.js. For example:

**layout.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%- contentFor('title') %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- content %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
contentFor('title', 'My title')

<h1>My content</h1>
```

It is important to me that however it works, the different layout contents are defined in the template, not passed in at the route level. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is not obvious at all. I was able to do this by:

1. setting a default context object
2. modifying that object in the template
3. referencing that object's properties in the layout

For example:

*setting the default context object*

```
server.register(plugins, (err) => {
    ...
    server.views({
        context: {
            layoutContent: {}
        }
    })
}
```

*modifying the object in the template*

```
// templates/my_template.html
<%
    layoutContent = {
        title: 'My Title'
        meta: '<meta name="description" content="my content">'
    }
%>
```

*referencing the object in the layout*

```
// layouts/layout.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%- layoutContent.title %></title>
        <%- layoutContent.meta %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- content %>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, you can either pass text or entire tags to the layout. Hope this helps.